# Find (& Delete) Specific Cached Entry - Microsoft DNS Server. Is it possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, cache, dns-server

I would appreciate your assistance on this.

I have a Microsoft DNS server, and am wondering if it is possible to find a specific cached entry (Cached Lookups) and delete it. I need to do this as some domains are resolving to old IP addresses on my network.

I'd rather delete the few specific entries than the whole cache. Is this possible?

(If it is not possible, is it better to delete the cache entry by entry or safe to proceed and delete the whole cache).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and safe to do either. You can delete a specific cached entry or you can clear the entire cache. If you clear the entire cache it will be "rebuilt" based on the queries that the DNS clients make.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Is there any way to find specific entries in Cached Lookups other than scrolling through the entries and opening each folder.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to find. All of the cached lookups are in alphabetical order. Open up the appropriate root zone (com, net, etc.) and find the particular domain.

Comment: Thank you for this direction. It's great information for me and guided me to find the specific entries to delete.

Comment: Glad to help...